# Max Request length exceeded when calling WCF service from TIBCO BW

Tags: c#, wcf, tibco

I have a WCF service which will be invoked by TIBCO BW, if the message size exceeds 5 MB, 
i am getting a System.IO exception on TIBCO BW. I have enabled tracing on wcf service, and getting **Maximum request length exceeded.** error

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this question for the various size/length related WCF settings:

[Maximum request length exceeded in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951763/maximum-request-length-exceeded-in-wcf)

Comment: hi, i have given maximum values for all the BINDING properties in web.config, but when invoking a WCF from TIBCO there is no concept of client side configuration.