# maxRequestLength is being exceeded on webservice WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, webserver, asmx

I'm having some trouble with my  webservice, the request is exceeding the max int size on my webservice I already had set the webconfig to this, but  it didn't work

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
```

is there someway to set this  bigger than 2147483647 ?

Yep, I  already  checked these answers on here  but none of them  had my  solution to this  issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximum request length exceeded in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951763/maximum-request-length-exceeded-in-wcf)

Comment: Can you share your WCF Configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the below configurations.
**Binding configuration.**

```
<binding name="mybinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
```

**DataConstractSerializer.**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="mybehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

Don’t forget to apply the configuration between the client-side and server-side (we are supposed to add this configuration on both the client-side and server-side endpoints).  Add the bindingConfiguration and behaviorConfiguration in the service section.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="mybehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search  we found this  solution setting  on webservice web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2200000000"/>              
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```